How to get a next line after a match using python regex
I'm relatively new to python and writing a code to get to the next line after a python regex match.
I looked into the examples like https://regex101.com/r/dQ0gR6/1 and after match, get next line in a file using python bit could not achieve what i intend to capture.
My text is:
FlowRole  SrcAddr        DstAddr        Proto   SrcPort  DstPort  Key Type Vrf   Dst Vrf  Service Instance Session Id Src Local Dst Local CP Redirect NH type   NH id
I         172.16.10.1    172.18.10.1    ICMP    21       2048     1        2     3        1                8389614    1         0         0           2         1
FlowRole  SrcAddr        DstAddr        Proto   SrcPort  DstPort  Key Type Vrf   Dst Vrf  Service Instance Session Id Src Local Dst Local CP Redirect NH type   NH id
R         172.18.10.1    172.18.10.110  ICMP    21       0        1        3     2        1                8389614    0         1         0           2         1

The code that i used to match is:
FlowRole[^\n]+([\r\n]\w+)    --> I;m able to match the line and the next line word but not the entire line..

need some help here.
I want to match the entire line after the pattern match
i.e., I want to match this these two lines:
I         172.16.10.1    172.18.10.1    ICMP    21       2048     1        2     3        1                8389614    1         0         0           2         1
R         172.18.10.1    172.18.10.110  ICMP    21       0        1        3     2        1                8389614    0         1         0           2         1


please elaborate: what do you want to match? what is the desired outcome?

You need re.findall(r'FlowRole.*\n(.+)', text), see https://ideone.com/j5BbZo and https://regex101.com/r/dQ0gR6/377

You were 90% of the way there, I Just changed the \w+ (which looks for only words characters but skips spaces) to [^\r\n] as you used previously to match the whole line) -
FlowRole[^\n]+[\r\n]([^\r\n]+)

This gives the expected output as per regex101

Mind that [^\n] = . in Python re. Just no need to use any additional modifiers/flags. AND [^\n]+[\r\n] is just the same as .+\n since [^\n]+ is greedy and \r from [\r\n] will never be matched unless it is a EOL separator.

While that is fair, I wanted to use pre-existing logic from the pattern to highlight/show where they went wrong and what they could have used based on what they shown to know. Also this works in the case the the s flag is used
